# using matlab VideoReader get a null object

Tags: linux, matlab, video

My OS is redhat. When I installed matlab2014b and used VideoReader('1.avi'), I got this message:

```
 >> VideoReader('1.avi')

 ans = 

 VideoReader with properties:

 General Properties:
       Name: '1.avi'
       Path: '/home/lyw/Videos'
   Duration: 0
CurrentTime: 0
        Tag: ''
   UserData: []

Video Properties:
       Width: 0
      Height: 0
   FrameRate: 0
BitsPerPixel: 0
 VideoFormat: ''
```

However, when I user aviinfo('1.avi'), I can got video infomation like this:

> > aviinfo('1.avi')

```
> In aviinfo at 66 
 ans =
        Filename: '/home/lyw/Videos/1.avi'
         FileSize: 3554002
       FileModDate: '26-Dec-2014 19:15:20'
         NumFrames: 749
   FramesPerSecond: 25
             Width: 688
            Height: 384
         ImageType: 'truecolor'
  VideoCompression: 'XVID'
           Quality: 0
NumColormapEntries: 0
```

I want to know how can I read the video ???? HELP!!!

Comment: Have you tried `VideoReader.getFileFormats()` and checked if `.avi` is listed?

Comment: I checked and .avi is listed. I can also successfully read the videos that the default player(Totem) of redhat can play. For other videos that player cannot play because of decoder, I failed to read these videos.

Comment: Strange. Sorry I can't help you with this, as I work with Windows and Mac. You could ask the MATLAB support for help, as this should definetly work.

Answer (score 0):

The AVI file appears to contain Xvid compressed data. On Linux, VideoReader uses Gstreamer to read videos. Are you sure you have suitable codecs installed on your system?

One quick way to verify this is to try the following on the Linux terminal (after copying file to /tmp) :

```
gst-launch-0.10 playbin2 uri=file:///tmp/1.avi
```

If this command succeeds, it indicates that gstreamer is able to read it in which case you should probably contact tech support.